# Xcode 10 archive contains no products

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode10

I have a macOS application project that uses a private framework built by a dependent target in a sub-project.  When I try to archive it with Xcode 10.2.1, there is no error message, but the archive shows up under "Other Items" rather than "macOS Apps" in the Organizer.  If I open up the archive package, the "Products" folder is empty, though the "dSYMs" folder has two items, one for the app and one for the framework.

Discussions of archiving problems usually mention setting SKIP_INSTALL to YES, and I did, in both the main project and the subproject.

I tried doing it on the command line with `xcodebuild archive -verbose`, but there was still no error message and it said ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED.

Is there any way to get Xcode to tell me what's bothering it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the trick was to set `SKIP_INSTALL=YES` on the framework, but `SKIP_INSTALL=NO` in the application project.  The other 3 combinations of these flags produce an archive that's bad in various ways.

I still wish Xcode was able to give me a hint rather than making me experiment.